# using the return/next key to set focus on the following UITextField

Tags: iphone

I have several fields, lets say 5 for now. I would like to press the return/next key and aloud the user to skip from one to the other to enter data in each. I have a UITableViewCell

```
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

        UITextField *FirstField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 130, 25)];
        FirstField.delegate = self;
        FirstField.tag = indexPath.row;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:FirstField];
        FirstField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyNext;
       [FirstField release];    
    }

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}
```

I am capturing every time the user presses the return/next key with the following:

```
// Handle any actions, after the return/next/done button is pressed

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textfield
```

But even if I know what cell/position/field, I am in, how do I tell the program focus on the next one? I know I have to use becomeFirstResponder, once I have the info.

Comment: is a good practice to have your variables starting with lower case (`firstField` instead of `FirstField`). As you see, even stack overflow automatic syntax highlighting gets a little confused.

Comment: You add tag from value 1.Not from zero.If u assigh indexPath.row, For the first row it will be zero.So assign tag like this

FirstField.tag = indexPath.row+1;

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by getting nextField using current tag
and make that Field as first responder.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
          int previouTag = textField.tag;
    if (previouTag<=numberOfRows) {
        UITextField *tempField=(UITextField *)[self.view viewWithTag:previouTag+1]; 
        [tempField becomeFirstResponder];
    }
}
```

Comment: EXC_BAD_ACCESS, your absolutely right! It works, now I just have to move the cells up every three returns/next pressed. I believe I saw code for this.  Thank you, I had read other post that made this seem an impossible task.

Comment: Something interesting thats happening, if I make numberOfRows a constant #define knumberOfRows 3 in the .h file, the compiler is giving me an error saying expected ) before ; token ??? Why is it not recognizing it?

Answer (score 0):

`

```
 -(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField  
{  
    BOOL finedNext = NO;  
    int  viewIndex = [self.mainScroll.subviews indexOfObject:textField];  
    for (int i = viewIndex+1; i < self.mainScroll.subviews.count; i++) {  
        if (!finedNext) {  
            UIView *view = [self.mainScroll.subviews objectAtIndex:i];  
            if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {  
                finedNext = YES;  
                [view becomeFirstResponder];  
            }  
        }  
    }  

    return YES;  
}
```

`